# How to use map efficiently instead for list and for loops

Tags: apex, map

I am trying to use map instead of list and for loops. So please suggest how to do it. Below is my scenario -

I have two objects Account and contact. There are two fields in contact Object Start_Date__c & End_Date__c.

I want to get all the Accounts whose contacts have the same Start & End Date. It can be different accounts.

Ex -

> Account1 is having 1 contact -

Cont1 with fields as Start_Date__c = 9/7/2017 & End_Date__c = 9/7/2017

> Account2 is having 1 contact -

Cont1 with fields as Start_Date__c = 9/7/2017 & End_Date__c = 9/7/2017

> Then i should get two Account as result - Account1 & Account2.

Below is the code which i am trying to write, but i am stuck -

```
List<Account> aList1=new List<Account>([select Id,Name from account]);
Set<Id> accid = new Set<Id>();
for(Account a1:aList1){
    accid.add(a1.Id);
}

List<Contact> con = [select id,Name,AccountId,Start_Date__c, End_Date__c from Contact where End_Date__c!=null AND Start_Date__c!=null AND AccountId IN: accid];

Map<Date, List<Account>> contactTocomp = new Map<Date, List<Account>>();

for(Contact c:con){

 List<Account> acclist = contactTocomp.get(c.Start_Date__c); 
    if(acclist ==null){
        acclist = new List<Account>();
    }
    system.debug('@@@@' + contactTocomp);
}
```

Comment: I am having a very hard time understanding what you need to do. Can you edit your question and clarify what you need?

Comment: i have edited it. Please let me know if it is clear..

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your approach could be like this. You can also pass list of Contact Ids to filter out the List of Contacts:

```
List<Contact> con = [SELECT Id,Name,AccountId,Start_Date__c, End_Date__c 
                        from Contact where End_Date__c!=null 
                        AND Start_Date__c!=null];

Set<Id> accidSet = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact c:con){

    if(c.Start_Date__c == c.End_Date__c)
    {
        accidSet.add(c.AccountId);
    }    
}
```

**Update based on Comments**

> What if the dates are like this - Account 1 -> Cont1 with fields as Start_Date__c = 9/7/2017 & End_Date__c = 10/7/2017. And Account2->Cont1 with fields as Start_Date__c = 9/7/2017 & End_Date__c = 10/7/2017

```
List<Contact> con = [SELECT Id,Name,AccountId,Start_Date__c, End_Date__c 
                        from Contact where End_Date__c!=null 
                        AND Start_Date__c!=null];

Set<Id> accidSet = new Set<Id>();

for(Contact c:con)
{
    for(Contact conObj: con)
    {
        if((c.Id != conObj.Id) && (c.Start_Date__c == conObj.Start_Date__c) && (c.End_Date__c == conObj.End_Date__c))
        {
            accidSet.add(c.AccountId);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What if the dates are like this - Account 1 -> Cont1 with fields as Start_Date__c = 9/7/2017 & End_Date__c = 10/7/2017. And Account2->Cont1 with fields as Start_Date__c = 9/7/2017 & End_Date__c = 10/7/2017

Comment: check my updated answer. next time you should articulate your question properly.

Comment: Sure Santanu.. Apologies for the confusion.. So if i need to use map .. how i can use it.. Can i replace the two for loops and use a single map...Can u please put some light on it..

Comment: Since you are comparing one record with the other records then it has to be 2 loops, regardless you're using list or map.

Comment: is my answer serves your purpose? otherwise you can try to put your logic and if you face any issues, post as a separate question.